# FlipClock is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've an error with FlipClock.js when I try to get event with on method.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock("2800", {
        clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
        countdown: true,
        callbacks: {
            stop: function() {
                window.location = 'index.php';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have this on console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).FlipClock is not a function

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Check if the JS has loaded that flipclock needs

Comment: Seems like maybe the flipclock library file(s) didn't load properly into your page.

Comment: or your jquery file loads before flipclock.

Comment: Or perhaps you are loading two versions of jQuery.js in page and the second wipes out plugins attached to the first

Comment: Indeed, there is an incompatibility with the jquery-ui.js file ... This file is in my footer while my flipclock.js file is in a page ... therefore above.

Is there a solution to fix this without moving my flipclock.js file to my footer below jquery-ui.js?

Comment: I doubt it has to do with jquery-ui but more likely you are loading a version of jquery.js for each

Comment: jquery-ui is a jquery "plugin" you need to load your javascript file iafter flibclock

Comment: @charlietfl which part? if you're trying to use a function from a file, you need to load that file before calling the function right? :)

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

The error tells you that FlipClock does not exist at the time you are trying to call it. The [documentation](https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock) tells you that you can install it with Bower:

```
bower install FlipClock
```

or npm

```
npm install flipclock
```

or download [ZIP](https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/releases).

If you downloaded the zip, then make sure you have added the necessary HTML for it.

Comment: Can the downvoter provide some information about the reason of the downvote? I would be happy to improve my answer.